# Flutter code loops infinitely even after data is loaded from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am using the following Flutter and Firebase code to scaffold out a page to a user

```
import 'package:fgd6ss/models/user.dart';
import 'package:fgd6ss/screens/user/usr_type.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class UsertLanding extends StatefulWidget {

  final Map code;
  UserLanding({this.code});

  User _user = User();
  bool dataLoaded = false;

  @override
  _UserLandingState createState() => _UserLandingState();
}

class _UserLandingState extends State<UserLanding> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isValidUser = false;
    dynamic userData;
    Map codeData = widget.code;


   try{
  var document = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('id',isEqualTo: codeData['id']);
  document.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot){
    if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          userData = snapshot.docs;
          widget._user.name = userData[0]['name'];
          widget._user.status = userData[0]['status'];
          widget._user.type = userData[0]['type'];
          print(widget._user.name);
        });
      }
    }
  });

}catch(e) {
  print('error firebase data fetch');
}

return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xfffefefe),
    body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text(
                  widget._user.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]
        )
    )
);

  }
}
```

As you can see from the above code, I have a print statement inside the query in try. When I run this code, I expect it to run once when the screen loads. But what happens is, the code keeps looping and prints out the users name again and again on the console. Is this expected? If not, what is causing this behaviour? If yes, will it cause increase in the document read quota count on Firebase end.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `separate` method and call this method into your `initState()`. `Build` function is run continuously so your print statement is printed in the loop. So try with the below code. `initState()` method run only once when you reach on to the page

```
class UsertLanding extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map code;

  UserLanding({this.code});

  User _user = User();
  bool dataLoaded = false;

  @override
  _UserLandingState createState() => _UserLandingState();
}

class _UserLandingState extends State<UserLanding> {
  bool isValidUser = false;
  dynamic userData;
  Map codeData;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    codeData = widget.code;
    getData();
  }

  getData() {
    try {
      var document = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where('id', isEqualTo: codeData['id']);
      document.get().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
          if (this.mounted) {
            setState(() {
              userData = snapshot.docs;
              widget._user.name = userData[0]['name'];
              widget._user.status = userData[0]['status'];
              widget._user.type = userData[0]['type'];
              print(widget._user.name);
            });
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('error firebase data fetch');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xfffefefe),
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Row(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              widget._user.name,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0),
            ),
          )
        ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function in the build method. So whenever the build method will be rebuilt or refreshed, it will call that function again and again. The better approach is to call it in your InitState so it will be called only once. Here is an example that might help you.

```
  @override
  initState() {
  getData();
  super.initState();
  }
```